# Problem with Maya 2017 Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10

I just moved to the Ubuntu 17.10 distribution and downloaded the Autodesk Maya 2017 in the Downloads folder.
When I searched for how to install this package was the answer that I download the package from the command line, so how I downloaded it before.
What commands should I follow to install the package on my downloads folder?
I updated my Ubuntu.

**Edit from comment:**

My problem is I want to install Maya 2017 on Ubuntu 17.10 I downloaded the software compatible with Ubuntu from one of the torrent sites and extracted the file Now I want to install the program what I do to install the program

Comment: Which tutorial/guide did you follow and what kind of package did you download? Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: any way i need install maya 2017

Comment: Just a friendly heads-up, you're not going to get much help from this website with poorly written questions with missing details (and reluctance to provide details after being requested to do so) like this. In reply to your comment above ("*6 views and there is no single answer*"), contrary to a popular belief, Ask Ubuntu is *not* a free tech-support for Ubuntu. It's just a community of users trying to answer each other's questions. Please take the [tour of the site](https://askubuntu.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: accept my apology 
because I do not know how to ask questions

  I use Google for translation

Forget my first question

My problem is
I want to install Maya 2017 on Ubuntu 17.10

I downloaded the software compatible with Ubuntu from one of the torrent sites and extracted the file

Now I want to install the program what I do to install the program

Comment: Installation process depends on the type of package, nobody will be able to help you without more info. What kind of package is it? Is there a readme file?

Comment: @pomsky More info was freely available. See [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1021049/225694)

Comment: You've been misled, there is no Ubuntu compatible version of Maya 2017

Comment: @ElderGeek Of course it was, I was just pointing out how poorly written (missing details) OP's question was (let alone being kinda an XY-problem).

Comment: @pomsky You'll get no argument from me on that score. I guess I'm still just too [eager to help...](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16264/are-we-truly-eager-to-help/16265#16265)

Comment: @ElderGeek Of course, we all are (well, mostly!). Then again I believe new-comers must also be taught. My first ever post here was probably worse that this one! :-D

Comment: @JarvisStark We were all new once. Welcome to AskUbuntu! I've edited your question to include the relevant details from your comment.  Comments can get deleted here without warning and for numerous reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Maya 2017 doesn't support installation on Ubuntu. The sytems supported include:

```
Microsoft® Windows® 7 (SP1) and Windows® 10 Professional operating system
Apple® Mac OS® X 10.10.5, and 10.11.x operating system
Red Hat® Enterprise Linux® 6.5  & 7.2 WS operating system
CentOS 6.5  & 7.2 Linux operating system
```

See the [system requirements.](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/System-requirements-for-Autodesk-Maya-2017.html)

One alternative would be to run a supported OS on a VM, and install it on that. However, since you downloaded via torrent there's no guarantee that you have what you think you have. You might be better served by downloading [from the source.](https://www.autodesk.com/education/free-software/maya)